# Rails devise error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise for registration.But even after login `current_user` is returning nil.

```
class Admins::DashboardController < ApplicationController

before_action :authenticate_user!

def show   
  @title="Admin Dashboard | eazy coach"
  logger.info current_user.specific.inspect
end

end
```

> error : NoMethodError (undefined method `specific' for nil:NilClass):

Comment: Maybe you meant `current_admin`, if it's it's controller (`class Admins::DashboardController`) ?

Comment: Actually I am using acts_as :user in admin model that's why I have added current_user.Even I checked with current_admin not working

Comment: Can you please check what your **user_signed_in?** or **admin_signed_in?** returns ?

Comment: both are returning false

Comment: Are you using [acts_as_user gem](https://github.com/IcaliaLabs/acts_as_user) ?

Comment: yes.in admin model acts_as :user and in user model actable

Comment: I assume you generated the Admin model using `rails generate devise Admin`? Do you have two user models?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using an `namespace :admins` in your routes file.

For this case, you need to access the user with `current_admins_user` or `current_admins_admin`